# iText7 to convert PDF to Tiff

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tiff, itext7

I am able to convert PDF to TIFF using iText but it generates a TIFF file per page. I would like to generate one TIFF file with all the pages.

Here is my code:

```java
final RenderingProperties properties = new RenderingProperties();
properties.setImageType(PdfRenderImageType.TIFF);
PdfToImageRenderer.renderPdf(new File(flatFileName), new File(destFileName)
    +"/my-custom-filename-%d", properties);
```

Comment: Welcome! You could improve this question by explaining in a bit more detail what happens when you try the commands you've listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-page TIFF output is not (yet) supported out of the box through a property setting. But it can be worked around quite easily, like this:

```java
BufferedImageReadyListener listener = new BufferedImageReadyListener() {
    TiffEncoder encoder = new TiffEncoder();
    @Override
    public void bufferedImageReady(BufferedImage bufferedImage, int pageNumber) {
        try {
            encoder.append(bufferedImage, destFileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
};

final RenderingProperties properties = new RenderingProperties();
properties.setImageType(PdfRenderImageType.TIFF);
PdfToImageRenderer.renderPdf(new File(flatFileName), properties, listener);
```